# PrettyPhoto Auto play Slideshow not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I have installed WordPress in the my local machine and using a theme named Happy Health, There was a default flex slider came with the theme, I have configured the slideshow and want to make this slideshow to auto play without clicking it manually

I checked inside the directory

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mainstreetpt\wp-content\themes\happyhealth\script

I just saw ten files for jquery and  found two files for flex slider, They are

> jquery.flexslider.js
>
> jquery.prettyPhoto.js

```
(function($) {
$.prettyPhoto = {version: '3.1.5'};

$.fn.prettyPhoto = function(pp_settings) {
    pp_settings = jQuery.extend({
        hook: 'rel', /* the attribute tag to use for prettyPhoto hooks. default: 'rel'. For HTML5, use "data-rel" or similar. */
        animation_speed: 'fast', /* fast/slow/normal */
        ajaxcallback: function() {},
        slideshow: 5000, /* false OR interval time in ms */
        autoplay_slideshow: false, /* true/false */
```

This is the sample code for jquery.prettyphoto.js, The autoplay here is not working

the exact files lies here (click this link) [jquery.prettyPhoto.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5x_8BSm0y3oZVJtR0RoU09wams/view?usp=sharing) and the second file is (click this link) [jquery.flexslider.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5x_8BSm0y3oZU1UYW96U25DcDA/view?usp=sharing) can you guys help in making the tabs autoplay

Comment: Use other plugin which gives options of auto play on load. [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-slider-2/) is what you are looking for ..

Comment: No bro.. I just wanted to make the tabs to autoplay not the sliders

Comment: Which Tab ? You have mentioned something like this :
want to make this **slideshow** to auto play without clicking it manually

Comment: and bro can tell me what is the difference between flex slider and tabs

Comment: Which plugin have you used ?

Comment: and it's not a plugin it just came with the happy health theme

Comment: answering your first question... the slideshow which came with the theme

Comment: Is it premium(pro) theme ?

Comment: Then I would suggest you to post same thing in thier support form.They will give solution of this 100%.

Comment: search for initialization code and add `autoplay_slideshow:true` in it. Also if possible, give us a demo where we can see something in action.

Comment: I made autoplay_slideshow: true; but still not working